# Vim: Different line-number color in the different modes

Tags: vim, highlighting, mode

I've just started using Vim and I find myself being confused on which mode I'm currently in.  I was wondering if it's possible to change the line number color (which I have displayed by default) in the different modes (command, visual, and insert) so that I can easily identify it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vim has an option called `showmode` that will put a message on the last line if you are not in normal mode.  See `:help 'showmode'` for more info.

If you really want to change the background of the number column while in insert mode, you could do something like the following:

```
autocmd InsertEnter * highlight LineNr ctermbg=red   guibg=red
autocmd InsertLeave * highlight LineNr ctermbg=black guibg=black
```

Note that this method will break if you are *bad* and use `C-c` to exit insert mode instead of `<Esc>` or `<C-[`.

<sub>Relevant `:help` tags: `autocmd`, `autocmd-events`, `highlight`, `highlight-groups`</sub>